# Possible meanings of "Путь ему туда заказан"

Tags: значения

Is it like this phrase can have two almost opposite meanings in Russian (one of which would be something like "The way to that place for him has already been ordered/provided/arranged", and the other one "That way is forbidden for him")?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Путь ему туда заказан` can mean *only* `The way there is forbidden for him.` Although `заказан` means both `ordered / booked` and `forbidden`, this word in such a phrase is usually understood correctly, as `forbidden`, because you can order tickets, a car, a plane, a yacht, but *not* the way.

Comment: No it is just an idiom. But it is well possible to заказать way.

Answer (score 1):

In modern Russian заказан only means booked/ordered.

This phrase is just an idiom which uses заказан in an archaic sense "forbidden". This meaning is so different from the familiar meaning of the word that it is often used in quotes, like [here](http://www.superomsk.ru/news/detail.php?ID=44237)

Answer (score 0):

In some contexts - yes, one may say 'the way there is booked/ordered', although I can hardly imagine such a context. Politians usually, if ever, don't pay for their ways.

Comment: "Для того чтобы Александру отправиться в любом направлении нужно для начала "заказать" путь у диспетчера." http://www.youreporter.ru/ugc/20130129/799691068.html